# Ensure RequireJS modules are invoked in an r.js optimised app

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, r.js

I have a module that just executes some code in order to overwrite some existing functionality. The module doesn't return any value. It looks a bit like this:

```
// module "patch.js"
define(function (require) {
    var lib = require("lib");
    lib.foo = function () {
        // overwrite foo function here
    }
});
```

I then define it as a dependency of my main app module, something like this:

```
// main.js
require.config({
    shim: {
        "app": {
            deps: ["patch"]
        }
    }
});
```

And then I kick off the app module like this:

```
// main.js
require(["app"],function (app) {
    app.start();
});
```

This works fine when running the unoptimised version. The "patch" module is loaded before app starts and the code inside it is invoked. All is well.

The problem starts when I optimise using r.js. I'm noticing that the "patch" module's code is being pulled into the optimised file but is never being invoked.

I can force it to invoke by explicitly calling `require("patch")` somewhere in my app code, but I'd rather just define this dependency in the config.

What's the reason for this difference in behaviour between un-optimised and optimised modules? Why is the unoptimised module automatically invoked, whereas the optimised module is included in the built file but never invoked? Can I work around it with config options? Can I change the way I'm defining my "patch" module to get the behaviour I'm after?

**== EDIT: Adding r.js config ==**

I'm using grunt-contrib-requirejs. The config is about as simple as it gets.

```
{
    baseUrl: "site/js",
    mainConfigFile: "site/js/main.js",
    out: "build/js/main.js",
    name: "main",
    optimize: "uglify2",
    removeCombined: false
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your r.js optimizer config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to point out

1. Shim config should be used only for NON-AMD modules. For instance you're trying to integrate a jQuery plugin that is not defined inside a `define` function. So this segment of code is not necessary and can even break your app:

   ```
   require.config({
       shim: {
           "app": {
               deps: ["patch"]
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Second, try to define the modules in your app in the r.js optimizer

   ```
   {
       baseUrl: "site/js",
       mainConfigFile: "site/js/main.js",
       out: "build/js/main.js",
       name: "main",
       optimize: "uglify2",
       removeCombined: false,
       modules : [
           {
               name : 'site/js/main.js'
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

In this way r.js will know how to bundle the main.js module and all of its dependencies correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, this got me on the right track. The key piece of info was related to your point 1 I think. Only use shim for config of non-AMD modules, not for bootstrapping deps of AMD modules, especially my main "app" module. I moved "app" out of shim and explicitly defined its main deps inside of "app" itself. Things seem much happier now. Thanks again.